# Select if text not emply or if empty then highest key value

Tags: sql, select, greatest-n-per-group

I am looking for an SQL Query to solve the problem below.
I have the following table:

```
Name | Description | RowNo

A    | emptyText   | 1
A    | emptyText   | 2
A    | xxx         | 3
B    | yyy         | 1
C    | emptyText   | 1
C    | zzz         | 2
D    | emptyText   | 1
```

and I want to select the rows where the Description is not emptyText or if there is only emptyText for a Name in the Description to get only the row with the maximum RowNo.
Or if you prefer the rows that they have the maximum RowNo value for a given Name are the only once I would like to get.

For the example above I would like to get the following outcome:

```
Name | Description | RowNo

A    | xxx         | 3
B    | yyy         | 1
C    | zzz         | 2
D    | emptyText   | 1
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Pleas tag with database (eg. SQL Server / Oracle / MySQL etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we assume that the *last* row number has the non-empty text and "EmptyText" is really `NULL`, then a simple aggregation will do:

```
select name, max(Description), max(RowNo)
from t
group by name;
```

If we assume that "EmptyText" is not really a string but `NULL` and that there is only one row to be returned per `Name`, then you can do:

```
select name, max(Description) as Description,
       coalesce( max(case when Description is not null then RowNo end),
                 max(RowNo)
               ) as RowNo
from t
group by name;
```

The more general answer to your question is:

```
select name, Description, Rowno
from t
where Description <> 'EmptyText'
union all
select name, max(Description), max(RowNo)
from t
where Description <> 'EmptyText' and
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.Name = t.Name and t2.Descrdiption <> 'EmptyText');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! In the meanwhile this is what I have also found out. The empty text was not NULL but a text without any char (''). So Aggregation did the job! Thanks a lot about the general answer though!

Answer (score 1):

Set up sample data (SQL Server):

```
select 'A' as Name, 'emptyText' as Description, 1 as RowNo into test union all
select 'A' as Name, 'emptyText' as Description, 2 as RowNo union all
select 'A' as Name, 'xxx' as Description, 3 as RowNo union all
select 'B' as Name, 'yyy' as Description, 1 as RowNo union all
select 'C' as Name, 'emptyText' as Description, 1 as RowNo union all
select 'C' as Name, 'zzz' as Description, 2 as RowNo union all
select 'D' as Name, 'emptyText' as Description, 1 as RowNo
```

Use [first_value()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql):

```
select distinct
   a.Name
  ,coalesce(first_value(nullif(Description, 'emptyText')) over (partition by Name order by RowNo desc), Description) as Description
  ,first_value(RowNo) over (partition by Name order by RowNo desc) as RowNo
from test a
```

Result:

```
| Name | Description | RowNo |
|------|-------------|-------|
| A    | xxx         | 3     |
| B    | yyy         | 1     |
| C    | zzz         | 2     |
| D    | emptyText   | 1     |
```

Comment: Although I do not understand why it works probably because I am not familiar with "coalesce". It is a neat solution :) Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You could try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name, Description, MAX(RowNo)
FROM table
```

Comment: The presence of `MAX()` creates an implicit `GROUP BY` clause that produces a single row of output. The query is actually invalid because the columns `Name` and `Description` in the `SELECT` clause do not appear in the `GROUP BY` clause.